# What is the HeartRate module used for FitBit?

Tags: javascript, sensors, fitbit, wearables

I'm trying to make an application for FitBit without using the companion app that will allow me to get the accelerometer data and heart rate.

The [Heart Rate Sensor Guide](https://dev.fitbit.com/guides/sensors/heart-rate/) of FitBit gives the following code, but does not exactly specify what the imported module is, except that it is the "HeartRate module":

```
// Import the HeartRate module
import { HeartRateSensor } from "heart-rate";

// Create a new instance of the HeartRateSensor object
var hrm = new HeartRateSensor();

hrm.onreading = function() {

  // Peek the current sensor values
  console.log("Current heart rate: " + hrm.heartRate);

  // Stop monitoring the sensor
  hrm.stop();
}

// Begin monitoring the sensor
hrm.start();
```

The example that [FitBit has on GitHub](https://github.com/Fitbit/sdk-hr-meter), also implements the code in a similar fashion, with the module being nowhere to be found.

When I attempted to run the code on Sublime Text, it gave the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

What can I do to get the heart rate data?

Answer (score 0):

For import to work, you need `@std/esm` package.